# Increment the key on a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following php array:

```
$month = array (
    'weeks'=> array(
        'w1'=> array(
          'd1'=> 'day one',
          'd2'=> 'day two',
          'd3'=> array(
             'H1' => 'hour one',
             'H2' => 'hour two' 
           )
        ),
        'w2'=> array(
          'd1'=> 'day one',
          'd2'=> 'day two'
        )
    )
);
```

I want to recursively iterate over the array and change the keys to reflect an incremented time from the start of the month. Like so (simplified):

```
$month = array (
    'weeks'=> array(
        '1'=> array(
          '1'=> 'day one',
          '2'=> 'day two',
          '3'=> array(
             '3' => 'hour one',
             '4' => 'hour two' 
           )
        ),
        '5'=> array(
          '5'=> 'day one',
          '6'=> 'day two'
        )
    )
);
```

Note: the counter is NOT incremented as it steps down to a child. This reflects that the start time for a Week and the start time for its First Day both share the same timestamp.  The counter increments for the next sibling AND the counter increments after a 'key/value' pair has no children.

Comment: You will have to write your own function for this, probably using a recursively called foreach loop with a static counter. If you did so and it didnt work, show your code and we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of 'nested arrays' with the output array exactly matching the structure of the input. The only difference is that the array keys are turned into 'almost' incrementing integer subscripts.

The 'almost' part comes from the fact that when 'nesting' down one level the first entry has the same subscript as the previous level.

The way i approached this is to use a recursive function, which will deal with the 'nesting', and a 'foreach' loop within each 'level as each entry in the array remains at the same 'level' in the output.

Output: This needs to contain many levels, rather than storing a path of subscripts to the current output 'level, i just pass an array 'by reference' that can be simply set by the appropriate code.

The code: **[running with the given input using PHP 5.3.19 at 'viper-7'](http://viper-7.com/3HmVKD)**

First the function that does the work:

Note: the $destWeeks and $idxNew variables are passed as 'references' this allows the code to amend them directly.

```
function reindexWeeks($sourceWeeks, &$destWeeks, &$idxNew)
{
    foreach($sourceWeeks as $sourceKey => $sourceValue) {
        if (is_array($sourceValue)) {
            $destWeeks[$idxNew] = array();
            reindexWeeks($sourceValue, $destWeeks[$idxNew], $idxNew);
        }
        else {
            $destWeeks[$idxNew] = $sourceValue;
            $idxNew++;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
$idxNew = 1;  // starting index.
$newWeeks = array(); // output array at the 'week' level

reindexWeeks($month['weeks'], $newWeeks, $idxNew); // re-index the array 

// output array..
$newMonth = array('weeks' => $newWeeks);
```

Output using the example provided in the question:

```
Array
(
    [weeks] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => day one
                    [2] => day two
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [3] => hour one
                            [4] => hour two
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [5] => day one
                    [6] => day two
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Very elegant/concise. In my attempts I failed to Pass by Reference.