# set id for each element in recursive array

Tags: php, recursion

i want to set an id or index for each element and sub and the sub of the sub and so on

```
<?php

    $data = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'a',
            'children' => array(
                array(
                    'title' => 'a-a',
                    'children' => array(
                        array(
                            'title' => 'a-a-a',
                            'children' => array(

                            )
                        )                
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'title' => 'a-b',
                    'children' => array(

                    )
                )                        
            )
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'b',
            'children' => array(

            )
        )
    );

?>
```

i'm looking for php code or function that work with recursion to add the **index** key witn number (desc) something like this output

```
<?php

    $data = array(
        array(
            'index' => 1,
            'children' => array(
                array(
                    'index' => 2,
                    'children' => array(
                        array(
                            'index' => 3,
                            'children' => array(

                            )
                        )                
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'index' => 4,
                    'children' => array(

                    )
                )                        
            )
        ),
        array(
            'index' => 5,
            'children' => array(

            )
        )
    );

?>
```

Comment: you need to look at `array_map()` or `array_walk()` functions. and you need to try write code yourself, becouse there is no functions like "add_index_to_all_subarrays()".

Comment: I did an answer to a similar requirement. I suspect a variant of this should do what you want. Just look at the 'array nesting' logic. [questions/24690199/increment-the-key-on-a-multidimensional-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690199/increment-the-key-on-a-multidimensional-array/24702871#24702871)

Comment: @RyanVincent that's what exactly i looking for but i can't make the code work for my array at my example

Comment: My apologies, as you are not changing keys but just adding an 'index => number' to certain nested arrays, it is a lot easier to just 'walk' the array, identifying when to insert the 'index' entry,and modify the array directly. I have supplied an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of 'nested arrays' where the individual arrays need:

```
1) an entry to be added: 'index' => <incrementing number> where there is a 'children' entry in the array.
2) an entry to be removed where: 'title' exists in the array.
```

As arrays can be 'nested' then 'recursion' is the most appropriate way to process the 'data' array.

I find it easier to modify the array 'in place' rather than build up the 'output' array. Therefore 'array references' (&$arrayEntry) are used quite a lot.

I use the supplied test data and test the 'required' array and 'indexed' array to be equal as regards 'structure'.

This is tested code: PHP 5.3.18 on Windows XP. **[Working code at: viper-7.com](http://viper-7.com/EGvUNE)**

The function that does the work:

```
function addChildrenIndex(&$destData, &$idxNew)
{
    foreach($destData as $currentKey => &$currentValue) { // pass be reference so i can amend it

        if (is_array($currentValue)) { // ensure is 'children' array

            if (isset($currentValue['children'])) { // add the 'index' entry
                $currentValue['index'] = $idxNew;
                $idxNew++;
            }

            if (isset($currentValue['title'])) { // remove the 'title' entry!
                unset($currentValue['title']);
            }
            // as it is an array we 'recurse' around it - always...
            addChildrenIndex($currentValue, $idxNew);
        }
    }
}
```

Driving Code:

```
$idxNew = 1;  // starting index.

// COPY the source data so i can test it later if required...
$indexedData = $data; // output array

addChildrenIndex($indexedData, $idxNew); // re-index the array 'in place'

// echo 'Required Array: <pre>';
// print_r($requiredData);
// echo '</pre>';

// echo 'OutputArray: <pre>';
// print_r($indexedData);
// echo '</pre>';

// test array structures to contain same entries...
var_dump($indexedData == $requiredData, 'ARE EQUAL?');
```

Required Test data: see question

Indexed Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [index] => 3
                                        )

                                )

                            [index] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [index] => 4
                        )

                )

            [index] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

            [index] => 5
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Once upon a time there a study that came to the conclusion that the biggest challenges a young padawan-programmer on his quest to become a Jedi-senior-programmers are:

> [...] there are three major semantic hurdles which trip up novice imperative programmers. In order they are:
>
> - assignment and sequence
> - **recursion** / iteration
> - concurrency

I first encountered this theory in Jeff Atwood's blog entry: [Separating Programming Sheep from Non-Programming Goats](http://blog.codinghorror.com/separating-programming-sheep-from-non-programming-goats/) which is based on the scientific paper: [The camel has two humps (working title)](http://www.eis.mdx.ac.uk/research/PhDArea/saeed/paper1.pdf)

This is the code that achieves what you want (minus the `echo` calls which are only to *visualize* the steps easier):

```php
function addIndexRecursive(&$data) {
    static $index = 0;
    echo "The index is: $index" . PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($data as &$item) {
        $index++;
        echo "The index was incremented: {$index}" . PHP_EOL;

        $item = array('index' => $index) + $item;
        echo "Add the index to the item with title: {$item['title']}" . PHP_EOL;

        if (count($item['children']) > 0) {
            echo "This item has children so call the index function" . PHP_EOL;
            addIndexRecursive($item['children'], $index);
        // this else branch is only for illustration  purposes only
        } else {
            echo "There are no children therefore I stop" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

So lets dissect it a bit.

First thing to notice: I [pass the array by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). It's just a matter of taste, I prefer to modify the array directly rather then building another copy.

The `static $index` will help me keep track of the current index and will be incremented for every item is encountered. Lets see what kind of black magic this `static` does (according to [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)):

> A static variable exists only in a local function scope, but it does not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.

`foreach ($data as &$item)` again I want the elements to be passed by reference so I can modify them directly in the loop.

Now that we discussed the implementation details lets see what the *back-trace* of the function would be:

```
addIndexRecursive was call and the index is: 0
The index was incremented: 1
Add the index to the item with title: a
This item has children so call the function
    addIndexRecursive was call and the index is: 1
    The index was incremented: 2
    Add the index to the item with title: a-a
    This item has children so call the function
        addIndexRecursive was call and the index is: 2
        The index was incremented: 3
        Add the index to the item with title: a-a-a
        There are no children therefore I stop
    The index was incremented: 4
    Add the index to the item with title: a-b
    There are no children therefore I stop
The index was incremented: 5
Add the index to the item with title: b
There are no children therefore I stop
```

You will keep running into these kind of problems so the sooner you grasp the recursion concept the better.